# Memória e processamento - Variáveis e verificação

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, otimização, declaração-de-variável

Há grande diferença para memória e processamento na forma de executar a verificação nesses dois exemplos? Se sim, porquê e como ambos se comportam na hora de executar os códigos.

Método 1:

```
var exam = FindExamByID(id);

if (exam == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

Método 2:

```
if (FindExamByID(id) == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz uma comparação com as duas formas só para comprovar. O primeiro:

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.1
IL_0001: stloc.0
IL_0002: ldarg.0
IL_0003: ldloc.0
IL_0004: call instance string C::FindExamByID(int32)
IL_0009: brtrue.s IL_0012
IL_000b: ldarg.0
IL_000c: call instance int32 C::NotFound()
IL_0011: ret
IL_0012: ldc.i4.1
IL_0013: ret
```

O segundo:

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.1
IL_0001: stloc.0
IL_0002: ldarg.0
IL_0003: ldloc.0
IL_0004: call instance string C::FindExamByID(int32)
IL_0009: brtrue.s IL_0012
IL_000b: ldarg.0
IL_000c: call instance int32 C::NotFound()
IL_0011: ret
IL_0012: ldc.i4.1
IL_0013: ret
```

[Pode ser conferido no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgNwFgBQMDMSBMCAwggN5YKVJ5gB2wCAsgBQCUZFVXAbgIYBOCMABMEAXgRpOXSn0EBTAB68AtuIQAxOsICiylQCEAngEkAIsxGsMmGVTAAzBMyWrxE2gFcIEduVt2MjAA7AgAcgD2wBoRnrTCbDaBCAC+0kGhUgGUadnUQvRM+GwceTwCQqISWcmOzlrxeqrG5pbC7GIe3r6lyVwh4VExcQnW6Vy5yQM1VJNUAA78YHzA8gUMkdGx8SViAHwIcEkLSytrAMrAS7QA5praTYamFnQMVuIHXj42KUA==).

É o mesmo *bytecode* então não tem como ser diferente em processamento ou consumo de memória, **neste caso**. Eu não posso garantir que em algum caso ocorra uma otimização fazendo de um jeito e que não seja possível da outra forma. Composto de outras partes o código gerado pode ser um pouco diferente e aí ter diferença. Uma simples reordenação de instruções pode fazer o processamento ter outro compromisso.

O `.maxstack 2` igual em ambos mostra que o fato de existir uma variável para suportar o valor não muda nada quando comparado com o *slot*  no *stack frame* necessário para o valor sem a variável.

Answer (score 0):

Não a diferença, a diferença a é apenas na leitura do código. Muitos programadores preferem colocar o retorno de uma função em uma variavel antes de fazer algum processamento com a mesma, alguns ja preferem usar a função diretamente, mas neste caso em específico não irá ter diferença.

Answer (score 0):

Não faz diferença se você estiver compilando utilizando o modo `Release` (com o optimize code ativado), o qual deveria ser utilizado para ambiente de produção. Em ambos os casos, o código `Intermediate Language` gerado pelo compilador é o que está descrito abaixo.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0001:  call       object MetodosTeste.Program::FindExamById(int32)
  IL_0006:  pop
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

O pseudo-código utilizado para gerar o `IL` acima foi este:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int id = 0;

            //var exam = FindExamById(id);

            if (FindExamById(id) == null)
                return;
        }

        static object FindExamById(int id)
        {
            return int.MinValue;
        }
    }
```